# Extract coordinates of polygon centroids and label them by polygon number

Tags: r, shapes, shapefile, r-sf

I import a csv of longitude and latitude coordinates and convert them to polygon shapefiles.  I place a grid over the polygons and find the centroid of each grid square.  I then extract the coordinates of the centroids and place it in a dataframe, but I need to be able to say which polygon a particular centroid is in.

```
#Create shapefile of polygons
polygon <- lapply(split(df, df$shape), function(x) { coords <- 
as.matrix(cbind(x$longitude, x$latitude)); list(rbind(coords, coords[1,]))}) 
Coord_Ref <- st_crs(4326)
polygon <-  st_sfc(st_multipolygon(x=polygon), crs = Coord_Ref)
polygon <-  st_cast(polygon, "POLYGON")

#Create grid and centroids
PolygonBits <- st_make_grid(polygon, cellsize=0.0002)
PolygonBitCentroids <- st_centroid(st_make_grid(polygon, cellsize=0.0002))

#Extract coordinates and place them in dataframe
PolygonBitCentroids <- st_coordinates(PolygonBitCentroids)
PolygonBitCentroids <- as.data.frame(PolygonBitCentroids)
```

The first three rows of the PolygonBitCentroids dataframe looks as follows:

```
         X      Y
1   -0.0014 0.1990
2   -0.0012 0.1990
3   -0.0010 0.1990
```

But I need something like this:

```
          X      Y  Shape
1   -0.0014 0.1990  Polygon 1
2   -0.0012 0.1990  Polygon 1
3   -0.0010 0.1990  Polygon 1
```

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(shape = c("polygon 1", "polygon 1", "polygon 1", 
"polygon 1", "polygon 2", "polygon 2", "polygon 2", "polygon 2", 
"polygon 3", "polygon 3", "polygon 3", "polygon 3", "polygon 4", 
"polygon 4", "polygon 4", "polygon 4"), longitude = c(0, 1, 1, 
0, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0), latitude = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, -2, -2, -0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(shape = structure(list(), 
class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), longitude = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_double", 
"collector")), latitude = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to do point-in-polygon via `st_join`.

This is pretty straightforward with the tidyverse, and I'm sure you can use the following to translate to base R.

<strike>(I took the liberty to change your reproducible data slightly, since `polygon 4` is not a valid polygon given that it only has 3 points):</strike>

First we create an `sf` from the xy dataframe

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

polygons <- polygons %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('longitude', 'latitude')) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)
```

When plotted, this looks like this
[image: the points]

```
polygons <- polygons %>%
  group_by(shape) %>%
  summarise(do_union=FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

This correctly creates the polygons from the points.

a call to `plot(polygons)` produces the following plot:
[image: the polygons]

(the `do_union=FALSE` argument is important because otherwise order is not preserved). Next we create a separate `sf` object for the grids:

```
grids <- polygons %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.2) %>%
  st_centroid() %>%
  st_sf()
```

Finally, we join the two `sf objects using` st_within`

```
grids %>% st_join(polygons, join = st_within)
```

What you get looks exactly as you asked for.

```
Simple feature collection with 92 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -1.9 ymin: -1.9 xmax: 1.9 ymax: 1.9
CRS:            EPSG:4326
First 10 features:
       shape          geometry
1       <NA> POINT (-1.9 -1.9)
2       <NA> POINT (-1.1 -1.9)
3       <NA> POINT (-0.9 -1.9)
4  polygon 3 POINT (-1.9 -1.7)
5       <NA> POINT (-1.7 -1.7)
6       <NA> POINT (-1.3 -1.7)
7  polygon 3 POINT (-1.1 -1.7)
8       <NA> POINT (-0.9 -1.7)
9  polygon 3 POINT (-1.9 -1.5)
10 polygon 3 POINT (-1.7 -1.5)
```

If you `plot` the output, you'll get

[image: grouped grid centroids]

Comment: When I cast the data to polygons using your method, they do not plot as squares but as triangles.  Try plotting polygons and you will see polygons 1, 2 and 3 plot as strange shapes

Comment: I have corrected my reproducible data now.  If you plot the polygons using my code, you will see they appear as squares

Comment: I updated my answer using your corrected data. I made a mistake with the summarise method (forgot to include the `do_union=FALSE`